# python ctypes structure wrong byte size

Tags: python, ctypes

So I'm trying to figure out why the size of my `ctypes.Structure` is not what it should be. My code is the following, theres also the calculation of what the size should be afaik.

```
class FILE_HEAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_char * 4),                    # 4 bytes
        ("size", ctypes.c_int),                         # 4 bytes
        ("Cal_l", ctypes.c_double),                     # 8 bytes
        ("Cal_r", ctypes.c_double),                     # 8 bytes
        ("Speed_ChL", ctypes.c_byte),                   # 1 byte
        ("Speed_Pulses_ChL", ctypes.c_int),             # 4 bytes
        ("Speed_factor_ChL", ctypes.c_double),          # 8 bytes
        ("Quantity_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 3),            # 3 bytes
        ("Description_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 32),        # 32 bytes
        ("Unit_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 8),                # 8 bytes
        ("Speed_ChR", ctypes.c_byte),                   # 1 byte
        ("Speed_Pulses_ChR", ctypes.c_int),             # 4 bytes
        ("Speed_factor_ChR", ctypes.c_double),          # 8 bytes
        ("Quantity_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 3),            # 3 bytes
        ("Description_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 32),        # 32 bytes
        ("Unit_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 8)                 # 8 bytes
    ]                                                   # = 136 bytes
```

So I think that Structure should have a size of 136 bytes. But when I let python print the size of an instance of the structure `print ctypes.sizeof(COMI_HEAD)` I get `144`. I do not know where those 8 bytes come from.

I've filled that with the following data and wrote that to a file to see all the bytes and analyze where the bytes are.

```
comi = FILE_HEAD()
comi.name = "COMI"
comi.size = ctypes.sizeof(comi) - 8
comi.Cal_l = 342.324
comi.Cal_r = 342.324
comi.Speed_ChL = ctypes.c_byte(1)
comi.Speed_Pulses_ChL = 123
comi.Speed_factor_ChL = 123.456
comi.Quantity_ChL = "Tes"
comi.Description_ChL = "Test Desc"
comi.Unit_ChL = "t/t"
comi.Speed_ChR = ctypes.c_byte(1)
comi.Speed_Pulses_ChR = 123
comi.Speed_factor_ChR = 123.456
comi.Quantity_ChR = "Tes"
comi.Description_ChR = "Test Desc"
comi.Unit_ChR = "t/t"
```

Here is what my HEX-Viewer shows me. I've marked red, which bytes I think are the 8 bytes that are too much, but I do not know where these 8 bytes come from. The first 3 bytes I marked come directly after the `Speed_ChL` which should be 1 byte but looks like its 4 bytes. The next 5 bytes I've marked are at the end of the file. Theres this string `Unit_ChR` which should be 8 bytes but looks like it is 13 bytes.

[image]

Can someone tell me where my mistake is? What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it's just aligning the members so they start at nice offsets.

Comment: ok... can I prevent that somehow? I really need that '0's to disappear

Comment: Not really sure. Are you serializing it? I think padding can be different depending on hardware so that's not a good idea.

Comment: That should write file information into the header of a file type. And it's defined how it has to be, so that '0's really shouldn't be there. Maybe I should directly write the values one after the other.

Comment: Thank you! Now I've found the solution myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I've found the solution. Thanks to Andreas who told me that my problem has to do with the [offset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order). So the solution is to add a `_pack_ = 1` to the structure like that.

```
class FILE_HEAD(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_char * 4),                    # 4 bytes
        ("size", ctypes.c_int),                         # 4 bytes
        ("Cal_l", ctypes.c_double),                     # 8 bytes
        ("Cal_r", ctypes.c_double),                     # 8 bytes
        ("Speed_ChL", ctypes.c_byte),                   # 1 byte
        ("Speed_Pulses_ChL", ctypes.c_int),             # 4 bytes
        ("Speed_factor_ChL", ctypes.c_double),          # 8 bytes
        ("Quantity_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 3),            # 3 bytes
        ("Description_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 32),        # 32 bytes
        ("Unit_ChL", ctypes.c_char * 8),                # 8 bytes
        ("Speed_ChR", ctypes.c_byte),                   # 1 byte
        ("Speed_Pulses_ChR", ctypes.c_int),             # 4 bytes
        ("Speed_factor_ChR", ctypes.c_double),          # 8 bytes
        ("Quantity_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 3),            # 3 bytes
        ("Description_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 32),        # 32 bytes
        ("Unit_ChR", ctypes.c_char * 8)                 # 8 bytes
    ]                                                   # = 136 bytes
```

Comment: Or use `FILE_HEAD = struct.Struct('<4siddbid3s32s8sbid3s32s8s');` `comi = FILE_HEAD.pack(b"COMI", FILE_HEAD.size - 8, 342.324, 342.324, 1, 123, 123.456, b"Tes", b"Test Desc", b"t/t", 1, 123, 123.456, b"Tes", b"Test Desc", b"t/t")`.

Comment: Note that you do get exactly the same problem programming in C and _worse still_ the solution tends to be compiler specific.

Comment: it was really helpful